# cant figure out issue with FileReader

Tags: java, filereader

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab4 {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        /*
         * Input is the name of the file and location typed by the user
         * file is used as a new scanner of the file to later go into the FileReader
         */

        String input;
        Scanner file;

        System.out.println("Please type the name of the file you wish to read into the program");

        // scanner to acquire input
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        input = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("the file input was " + input);

        // tries to attach the specified file "input" to a new scanner "file" to later read into FileReader
        try{
            file = new Scanner(new File(input));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("The requested file could not be found");
        }

         FileReader(File file){
            while(file.hasNext()){
                String s = file.next();

            }
       }
    }

}
```

after several long issues with programming I got to where  compile after each new addition
I hit errors on FileReader, I have looked up examples and what im doing should be right,

```
java: ')' expected
java: illegal start of expression
java: ';' expected
java: class, interface, or enum expected
```

the errors point to the location of FileReader so apparently I'm using it wrong, I DO NOT need ; the examples I seen were makeing methods like public void FileReader(File "fileName")
I was told to put the entirety of my code in public static void main(String[] args)

I watched youtube and looked up the API and no dice.

Comment: What do you think that `FileReader` block is doing? It looks like  a method inside a method (which you can't do), so depending what you expect, you could make it a method or just create a FileReader instance.

Answer (score 1):

A better coding practice is probably to define the local variables `input` and `file` outside of the main() method ...

`public static String input;` like this...

`public static Scanner file;` and this...

Although, the program will still work because the code initialized these local variables before use.  I thought this may of been a problem at first as sometimes the compiler can be tricky to interpret. Nevertheless, it does not hurt to declare these variables outside of main as long as they use the `static` modifier to work with the static context of main().

Java will not automatically initialize local variables.  This can cause errors if they are not initialized before use in a method.

Also FileReader is a class and cannot be used in the same way as a method. 
First, the FileReader object should be instantiated. After this you can call methods on the object reference and change the state of member fields on the FileReader object through the reference.

According to the Java 7 API you can instantiate a java.io.FileReader object in 3 ways. 
One way takes a File object, another takes a String object, and another takes a different kind of object I am not familiar with.

So for example you could instantiate a FileReader like so:

```
   FileReader fR = new FileReader("myfile.csv");
```

or

```
   FileReader fR2 = new FileReader(new File("myOtherFile.txt"));
```

Read this documentation when you have some time:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Also, check out this guys code on reading in a file: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/

Finally, I edited your program to read a file:

```
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileReader;
  import java.util.Scanner;
  import java.io.*;

  public class lab4 {

static BufferedReader br = null;


public static void main(String[] args){
String s = null;

    /*
     * Input is the name of the file and location typed by the user
     * file is used as a new scanner of the file to later go into the FileReader
     */

    String input;
    Scanner file;

    System.out.println("Please type the name of the file you wish to read into the program");

    // scanner to acquire input
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    input = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("the file input was " + input);

    // tries to attach the specified file "input" to a new scanner "file" to later read into FileReader
    try{
       // wrap the FileReader object instantiated from the input variable in a 
       // BufferedReader object 
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));

    // read each line to the console in this while loop that runs as long as it does not equal null
    while((s = br.readLine()) != null){ 
    System.out.println(s);
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("The requested file could not be found");
    }


 }

}
```

Happy Coding!

Please let me know if this works.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably run through the basics of Java before doing anything like this.

Regardless, here's a sample:

```
    try
    {
        File file = new File("input-file.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String line = null;
        while ( (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null )
        {
            // do stuff with the line that was read
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Yeah its my second programming class, just got introduced to FileReader :S. Soo still in basics ^_^ thanks for the help! im thinking about just stripping my code inside main String and going with the youtube tutorial, just cant make it work like this will see some examples friday and wont loose too many points doing it the other way.

Comment: I didn't mean to discourage you, that's pretty damn good for a second class. You'll get the hang of it after a while. `FileReader` is a class that you "instantiate", not a method that you call (as you've written) - that's really the only misunderstanding. Good luck fellow coder!